# JMeter 3.2 source not compiling

Tags: java, jmeter, bouncycastle, jmeter-3.2

I try to work with JMeter 3.2 source but it's not compiling, It was missing mainly Bouncy Castle jars I added jars but still getting an error:

SMIMEAssertion.java include constructor `SMIMESignedParser(BcDigestCalculatorProvider, MimeMultipart)` which doesn't exists in JMeter's lib, Code failing:

```
s = new SMIMESignedParser(new BcDigestCalculatorProvider(), multipart);

s = new SMIMESignedParser(new BcDigestCalculatorProvider(), msg);
```

I added different jars of Bouncy Castle as latest `bcprov-jdk15on-158.jar` to older versions `bcmail-jdk14-1.46.jar` or others as `bcpkix-jdk15on-1.55` or `bcmail-jdk15-140.jar` but still failed to compile

Does anyone knows the correct jars to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter uses "ant" to build.

Based on https://github.com/apache/jmeter it looks like they use Travis to build and test (probably on Github).

Based on

```
before_script:
  - test "x$RUN_CHECKSTYLE" != 'x' || ant -Djava.awt.headless=true download_jars install
```

(https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/.travis.yml)

it appears that you should run

> ant download_jars

to get the jars you need.  Locate them and add them to your build path.

(And this stuff is exactly why projects are typically migrating to Maven)

---

*Edited in by other user after I wrote it:*

Full explanation for building is here:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/building.html

A PR of migration to maven is available and should be merged after 3.3 release.

Comment: From ant build it's bcmail-jdk15-*.jar bcprov-jdk15-*.jar

Comment: I found jars in build.properties